# Cómo separar texto de una celda desde el último espacio en Excel

Tags: excel

tengo el siguiente problema: Tengo una columna llena de datos con el siguiente formato

| Producto. |
| --- |
| Arroz popular 12undx1kg |
| Aceite marca vegetal 20undx900ml |
| Atún desmenuzado del mar 24x170grs |

Y deseo separarlas por el último espacio pero no he encontrado la manera, intenté con la opción de excel **texto a columnas** pero este lo que hace es separar por todos los espacios

Answer (score 0):

Para extraer la última palabra de una celda necesitas crear una fórmula usando varias funciones:

`=ESPACIOS(DERECHA(SUSTITUIR(A2," ",REPETIR(" ",LARGO(A2))),LARGO(A2)))`

- `LARGO()` Calcula el número de caracteres de la celda
- `REPETIR()` Repite un espacio vacío (*o el caracter que se le pase en el primer parámetro*) la cantidad de veces que se obtiene con `LARGO()`
- `SUSTITUIR()` Encuentra todos los espacios en blanco en la celda y los reemplaza por el caracter dado en `REPETIR()` *en este caso, espacios vacíos*
- `DERECHA()` Extrae los últimos X caracteres de la celda, es decir la cantidad obtenida en `LARGO()`
- `ESPACIOS()` Elimina todos los espacios iniciales y finales del texto y devuelve sólo la última palabra:

**Debes tener cuidado, el caracter separador dentro de cada función, puede ser coma o punto y coma dependeindo de cómo esté parametrizado en la configuración regional de tu computador**

Vas a obtener una salida como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]